# Email to case: different filtering for replies and new emails

Tags: email, email2case, servicecloud

I'm looking for help related to the **Email-to-case** functionality.

I'd like to:

1. Enable **case creation from email sent only by internal
   Salesforce users** (we can distinguish them by the email address
   domain), not from the external users (any people outside the company).
2. At the same time **allow both internal and external users (Exp. Cloud users) to reply to the email notifications** related to their cases. Such a reply creates a feed item under the case and Salesforce Service Cloud users see this reply on the feed. This works thanks to thread id included in the notification (see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.support_email_to_case_threading.htm&type=5).

The second requirement makes it impossible to use the *Accept Email From* setting from Email-to-case configuration (see https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizesupport_configuring_routing_addresses.htm&type=5) that simply filters the domains of the incoming emails.

How can I achieve the #1 point without losing the #2? Unfortunately, custom email handler is not an option for me (timelines).

Comment: Why not change the Case.Contact to point at the Experience cloud user after the initial E2C case is created?

Comment: Are you using email-to-case to receive email only from internal users and from Experience Cloud users?  Or are you also accepting emailed cases from the general public (who may not have a user / contact record)?

Comment: @cropredy I didn't get your point - we can do that, but still it doesn't solve the problem of allowing only internal users to create cases via E2E (external users can only create feed items via replies - not the new cases).

Comment: @DavidCheng we have 2 scenarios:
1. E2C for Case creation - here we want to create cases only from emails sent by internal users.
2. E2C for notifications replies that create feed items - this is available for every email (doesn't even have to be Exp. Cloud user), but since the notifications are sent only to registered internal/Exp. Cloud users, the usual scenario will not include replies from random people.

Comment: You're right -- the E2C domain block would prevent the threaded replies from coming in from the Experience users. Hmm.  You could remove the allowList and use VR to block creation of cases where origin = email and domain not internal; but VR would allow new email message threaded replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gathered a few different ideas:

1. **Forwarding filters on the "middle-inbox" (the one that routes emails to the Salesforce routing address).**
2. Two separate E2C routing addresses - one for email replies, one for new
   cases - this gives control over domains in Salesforce.
3. Exception throwing in Apex trigger or validation rule
   (admin added through *Email for Automated Case User Notifications* in *Support Settings* swill start receiving error emails, but will be able to filter them out by the specific error message).
4. Cases deletion by origin.

I'm going to choose **#1** as it seems relatively simple and clean. Apart from that, I might not avoid email filtering regardless of the chosen solution anyway (suppose I may want to additionally filter out the Out Of Office replies).